# $f(x):=x^4+ax^3+\frac{3}{2}x^2+1$. For which constant $a$ the function $f$ will be convex on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: calculus, analysis, functions, derivatives

> $f(x)=x^4+ax^3+\frac{3}{2}x^2+1$.
>
> For which constant $a$ the function $f$ will be convex on $\mathbb{R}$?

The first derivative of the function will be: $4{x}^{3}+3a{x}^{2}+3x$

A function $f(x)$ is convex on an interval$ [a,b]$ if for any two points$ x_1$ and $x_2$ in $[a,b]$ and any $\lambda$ where $0<\lambda<1$ we have

$f(\lambda x_{1}+(1-\lambda)x_{2})\le\lambda f(x_{1})+(1-\lambda)f(x_{2})$

How can I compute the value of a?

Answer (score 5):

A real function is convex if the second derivative is non-negative anywhere.
$$
f''(x)=12x^2+6ax+3=3(2x+a/2)^2+3(1-a^2/4)
$$

Comment: Just a note: Some non-differentiable functions can still be convex but this works fine for polynomials.

Comment: You may also check that that quadratic is non-negative anywhere by looking at its discriminant.